# Importing GeoJSON without duplicating values in properties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geojson, arcgis-pro

Here is the issue I am having, it should be fully reproducible. I am attempting to import a [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) into [ArcGIS Pro](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-pro/overview). The issue is that if one of the features has a property that the other doesn't, instead of it being null in the attribute table, ArcGIS uses the last features value as the new features value.

I included a tiny GeoJSON that should reproduce the issue. I am importing it through json -> features.

```json
{
    "features": [{
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [-74.2462, 43.4674],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties": {
            "area": "",
            "height": "25",
            "id": "13784",
            "link": "https://digthefalls.com/auger-falls-wells/",
            "name": "Auger Falls",
            "node_type": "waterfall",
            "waterway": "Sacandaga River"
        },
        "type": "Feature"
    }, {
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [-74.6567, 43.6012],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties": {
            "area": "West Canada Lake Wilderness",
            "id": "13785",
            "name": "Brooktrout Lake Shelter",
            "node_type": "lean-to"
        },
        "type": "Feature"
    }],
    "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

When imported, the second feature in the GeoJSON will have the same link as the first feature in the GeoJSON. I would like the second features link to be null.

Comment: Bug reports should be submitted to GIS software vendors.

Comment: I have submitted it there now but was wondering if this is a bug or if I need to do something in order for null values to be allowed.

Comment: Does "height" behave in the say way?

Comment: @user30184 Indeed "height" does behave in the same way